# How to restrict first character alphabet only for a given input field using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text field , `<input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" ng-model="firstName">` in that text field first character must be alphabet only , when user try to enter first character not a alphabet not accepting.

Answer (score 3):

Generic regex check of first string character.

```js
var testString= "This is testString"
console.log(testString+" - "+alphabeticalFirstChar(testString));


testString= "1This is testString"
console.log(testString+" - "+alphabeticalFirstChar(testString));

testString= "This is testString0"
console.log(testString+" - "+alphabeticalFirstChar(testString));

testString= ""
console.log(testString+" - "+alphabeticalFirstChar(testString));

function alphabeticalFirstChar(str){
   if(/^[A-z]+$/.test(str[0]) && !str.length<1)//added check for str not being empty - returns true otherwise
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you apply your regex to asked question which is angularjs

Comment: @moguzalp does angularjs change / offer different solution? I mean this solution seems pretty generic to me and should work with any js based framework... Right?

Comment: @moguzalp tbh i don't have a background knowledge of angularjs... Someone who does can edit my generic answer to a specific solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.firstName = "";
  var regex = /^[A-z]+$/;
  $scope.$watch('firstName', function(newValue, oldValue){
      if($scope.firstName.length > 0){
          if(regex.test(newValue)){
              $scope.firstName = oldValue;
          }
      }
  });      
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" ng-model="firstName">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('controller', function($scope) {
 $scope.password;
 $scope.check = function () {
  if($scope.password != null){
   var charArray = $scope.password.split('');
   console.log(charArray);
   if(/[a-zA-Z\_]$/.test(charArray[0]) && charArray[0] != null) {
    return true;
   }
   else {
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller">
  <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
 <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-2/256/success-icon.png" ng-show="check()" width="25" height="25"/>
   <img src="https://dialectline.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/sign-error-icon.png" ng-show="!check()" width="25" height="25"/>
  
 </div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: `.split('')` is not really needed. String can automatically act as an array of characters. - Otherwise nicely done answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" ng-model="firstName" ng-change="checkAlphabet()">
```

In Controller

```
$scope.checkAlphabet = function() {
    if($scope.firstName.substr(0, 1).match(/[A-Za-z]/) == null)
        $scope.firstName = $scope.firstName.substr(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example using [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) using regex as pointed by **@Adam**

Follow: https://jsfiddle.net/nirus/3Lytwybr/2/

**Javascript:**

```
function LoginController($scope) {
   $scope.user = {
      firstName: ""
   };
   $scope.$watch('user.firstName', function(){
        console.log("changed");
      var cache = $scope.user.firstName;
      if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test($scope.user.firstName[0]))){         
        $scope.user.firstName = cache.slice(1,cache.length);
        console.log("here: "+ cache)
      }
   })
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>Hello {{ user.firstName }}</div>
    <input ng-model="user.firstName" />
</div>
```

> **Note :** Avoid using too many watchers as it hampers the performance of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I modified Adam K`s  code and translated it into angular.

```
if(/^[A-z]+$/.test($scope.firstname[0]) == false) {
  $scope.firstname = ""; }
```

Hope it helped.